# phpMyAdmin -- import one table into existing database

Tags: import, phpmyadmin

I have a new table I want to add to an existing db, the structure of which I exported to a file table.sql.

table.sql has 75 columns, so naturally I would rather find a way to copy/import the structure into the existing db than creating a new table and manually defining each of the 75 fields.

Is there a way to import this table structure into my database mydb (which is populated with data)? There has to be -- this is computing. I am staring at phpmyadmin and can't figure out how to do this.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

okay, figured out how to do it. I just opened the exported .sql file, and copied/pasted the "CREATE TABLE..." statement into the DB's SQL window in phpMyAdmin and it worked -- I now have that new 75-column table.

But I'm still a bit mystified over why phpmyadmin gave a success message when I tried to import the .sql file but did not display the allegedly imported table.

Comment: Good! I was wondering if that would work. I don't know why it didn't work to import. If you think it is a bug, maybe you should report it to phpMyAdmin: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues

Answer (score 0):

There is an Import tab in phpMyAdmin. 
Open the database you would like to import into, then click on the "Import" tab and upload your file.
You can learn more here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/import-and-export-databases-using-phpmyadmin/

An alternate way would be to copy the mySQL statement(s) in your table.sql file, open the "SQL" tab, paste it in the box, and then the run the query.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

It's easy. You should choose your database then in the Import tab, select choose file. Select your file then press Go. It worked for me. You can find the new table in your database.

Comment: What does this answer contribute to the discussion? An Answer with the same information (and more) was posted more than three years ago. Answers should be contributed only when the add information. Repeating already available information is not useful.